# stop eclipse from deleting folders inside "target"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium

I am developing a `maven` project with **Spring mvc application** with **Eclipse**. I have some cucumber-selenium test case to check the some behavior of app. I put the `chromDriver.exe` in the path `target\classes\Driver`.

When i want to run the application it complains about:

```
The project was not built due to "Could not delete '/CyberMall/target/classes/Driver'.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent CyberMall       Unknown Java Problem
```

It seems that, it tries to delete the `Driver` folder inside the `target`, and it fails, so it cannot build the application.

So, **is there any way to ask Eclipse to stop deleting the Driver folder?**

The reason I have put the driver in this path is that, i can easily access to it using the below code.

```
File file = new File(CyberMallApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResource("Driver/chromedriver.exe").getFile());
        String driverPath=file.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(driverPath);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",driverPath);
```

**If i put it into the resources, i don't know how to access it?**

Comment: Try putting `chromDriver.exe` in `src/main/resources` instead .

Comment: The `target` folder is meant to receive the build's output and thus needs to be cleaned eventually. Putting stuff that's not meant to be deleted there isn't a wise choice.

Comment: @Berger i have updated my question

Comment: I updated my response to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `chromedriver.exe` to `src/main/resources` and set relative path in the system properties

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/chromedriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not a good practice to put a file that should be used in the targer folder.

The target folder should be clean at every maven install so the content is deleted.

You can put your file in the resources folder insted.

Take a look at that link : https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

> The target directory is used to house all output of the build.

The content of the resource directory will be put inside WEB-INF/classes. So you can adapt your resources folder to have your folders like you already have.

resources/Driver/chromedriver.exe